# Python 2 subtitle language characters are wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I am complete noob for coding. Trying to learn Python 2. Now I create a script which plays the video and manage to import subtitle. But Turkish subtittle characters are wrong like (ı to ẏ , ş to þ ). If anyone can help I will appreciate it. Here is my code;

```
import vlc

import time

Instance = vlc.Instance()

player = vlc.MediaPlayer ("Path here")

player.play()

time.sleep(25)

player.video_set_subtitle_file("Path here")
```

When I try to import vlc with Python 3 I got this massage;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ozan/PycharmProjects/vlc/vlc7.py", line 1, in <module>
    import vlc
  File "C:\Users\Ozan\PycharmProjects\vlc\venv1\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 210, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "C:\Users\Ozan\PycharmProjects\vlc\venv1\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 170, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL('.\\' + libname)
  File "C:\Users\Ozan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\Ozan\PycharmProjects\vlc\libvlc.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Comment: Somewhere you should tell vlc about which character encoding, or you should transcode the text and feed it to vlc.  in any case: Python 2 is obsolete (and with own problems with encoding). If you can use Python 3 (and you have python 3 vlc libraries), I think all encoding stuffs will become easier (no need to second guess what encoding expect every module)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for reply. I tried also Python 3 but couldnt import vlc in there properly. I got this massage when I try to import vlc in Python 3.8;

Comment: Maybe you should try reinstalling the vlc module with pip.

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: @TejasJoshi I tried it, still not working.

Comment: Well then, maybe it's a bug in pycharm? I don't know what to do then.

Comment: You seem to have subtitles in some legacy 8-bit character set (ISO-8859-9?) and VLC is apparently displaying them in another (ISO-8859-1 or maybe some Windows atrocity?) Perhaps there's a way to convert them to modern Unicode / UTF-8 going forward?

Comment: I have deleted both python-vlc pip from 2.7 and 3.8 and reinstall only to 3.8. Tried to restart machine. Still not working on 3.8. On 2.7 i still able to run it without any issue beside subtitle.